# Slow Cheetah not working in when building

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, slowcheetah

I have added Cheeatah to simplify managing my configuration.

I can see the changes in the Preview.  But when I look at the config when I build I dont see it transforming my config file. I have selected the configuration and click build.  Am I missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the configuration file reference in the project file  as the TransformOnBuild node with a value of True, below is an example:

```
<None Include="App.config">
    <TransformOnBuild>True</TransformOnBuild>
</None>
```

Comment: thanks I made a branch for adding slow cheetah as well as build properties and that property got removed.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Kieron's answer, in my situation, `<TransformOnBuild>` was only set for Designer. Just had to delete that condition:

```
<None Include="App.config">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
</None>
```

Answer (score 0):

An other situation in which the same error occurs:

```
<Content Include="Castle.Config.Xml">
    <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
 </Content>
```

Problem: TransformOnBuild vs CopyToOutputDirectory!

"TransformOnBuild" is a implicit "CopyToOutputDirectory". If you define both, first the transformation is done, then "copy" overrides you transformed file.

This situation in our project happend cause a developer has set the copy tag accidentially. It seems, that the order was not in all situations the same. Removing the CopyToOutputDirectory solves this problem.

This version works as expected:

```
<Content Include="Castle.Config.Xml">
    <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
</Content>
```